# TestFlight: Message “Unable to Download Application” when trying to download

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

I'm using Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2 for iPhone 6. When I try to download app from Test-Flight it download all the way and show me this error message:

```
"Unable to Download Application" Retry (or) Done
```

Some of my beta-testers (internal) also had same error message but not all. It was working a couple of days ago and I'm not changing anything except bug fixes in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the message you are getting?

Comment: Like it says in title, "unable to download, retry / done"

Comment: This is usually a provisioning issue. With TestFlight you no longer need to manage device UUID's of your internal testers manually — however you need to make sure iTunes Connect is aware of which Apple accounts are internal testers and which aren't. Have you double checked your provisioning profiles?  Perhaps Xcode suggested provisioning profile fixes that actually screwed up your profiles (never use Xcode's 'Fix issue' for this reason!)?

Comment: Wow! You are the man  @fatuhoku. When I upload to Apple, I replace the provision profile with the one I generated it works! Thank you. Can you answer that in "Answer" so that I can complete and close this question.

Comment: Glad to have helped! I've just written up the relevant part as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a provisioning issue. Double check your provisioning profiles. Sometimes Xcode suggests provisioning profile fixes that can actually screw up your profiles. I tend to never use Xcode's 'Fix issue' for this reason!

Comment: Thanks again @fatuhoku.